# Pip install Boxsdk with JWT Oath not functioning as expected

Tags: python, sdk, pip, jwt

This is a pretty straightforward question I am hoping someone can help explain.  In the boxsdk repo they give a quick example how to set up boxsdk with JWT OAth. (https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk)

They provide the following code:

```
 pip install boxsdk[jwt]
```

However - this pip install doesn't work as a result of the square brackets.
Question: What are the square brackets around the jwt indicative of and why won't that install?

The standard installation with underlying repositories seems to work however when I run the code to instantiate the JWTAuth class....

```
from boxsdk import JWTAuth

auth = JWTAuth(
client_id='XXXX',
client_secret='XXX',
enterprise_id=12345,
jwt_key_id='XXXX',
rsa_private_key_file_sys_path='/path/CERT.PEM',)
```

I get a ...

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Which leads me to believe that the

```
pip install boxsdk[jwt]
```

is relevant to the issue at hand as I couldn't find a culprit in my call or in the code in the sdk.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone has the same issue:

```
pip install "boxsdk[jwt]"
```

resolved the issue.  Something about the square brackets broke the command at the command line.